# JavaMail API does not send email

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I need to send an e-mail from my Android application.
This is my code:

**Config.java**

```
public class Config {
    public static final String EMAIL ="your-gmail-username";
    public static final String PASSWORD ="your-gmail-password";
}
```

**Sendmail.java**

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;
 
import java.util.Properties;
 
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
 
 
//Class is extending AsyncTask because this class is going to perform a networking operation
public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
 
    //Declaring Variables
    private Context context;
    private Session session;
 
    //Information to send email
    private String email;
    private String subject;
    private String message;
 
    //Progressdialog to show while sending email
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
 
    //Class Constructor
    public SendMail(Context context, String email, String subject, String message){
        //Initializing variables
        this.context = context;
        this.email = email;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.message = message;
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Showing progress dialog while sending email
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Sending message","Please wait...",false,false);
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        //Dismissing the progress dialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        //Showing a success message
        Toast.makeText(context,"Message Sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
 
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Creating properties
        Properties props = new Properties();
 
        //Configuring properties for gmail
        //If you are not using gmail you may need to change the values
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
 
        //Creating a new session
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    //Authenticating the password
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(Config.EMAIL, Config.PASSWORD);
                    }
                });
 
        try {
            //Creating MimeMessage object
            MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);
 
            //Setting sender address
            mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Config.EMAIL));
            //Adding receiver
            mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
            //Adding subject
            mm.setSubject(subject);
            //Adding message
            mm.setText(message);
 
            //Sending email
            Transport.send(mm);
 
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And when a button is pressed, this is the `OnClick` code:

```
SendMail sm = new SendMail(this, email, subject, message);
sm.execute();
```

Now, the code gets locked inside `Transport.send(mm)` in `Sendmail.java` but I do not understand why since the configuration seems correct (seen on official Google websites).
It does not throw any exceptions (not even timeout exceptions) so I don't know where the problem might be.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

**update** the error is No `Network Security Config specified` but I did specify it! It's SSL

Comment: The password being a `public static final String` doesn't look like a good idea

Comment: @matteo-nnz yeah it's just a test currently, I'd just like it to work for now ahah

Comment: If you set some breakpoints inside the .send of Transport, are you able to identify the exact line where it hangs? That may help finding an answer, indeed your code looks correct to me at first sight.

Comment: can you please attached the error (snapshot) because maybe the email not configure with less secure

Comment: @MatteoNNZ the problem is in Transport.connect()

Comment: Transport.connect() is almost 100 lines of code without considering calls to other functions. Can you dive deeper?

Comment: @ala-eddine-hmidi the error is No Network Security Config specified, using platform default.

Comment: Are you run on emulator? 
did you try on a physical device?

Comment: If you are getting this error on emulator then may be it is because of firewall.